# Node JS Error EADDRNOTAVAIL after changing my computer name on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos

My node project was working properly on my Mac until I changed my computer name to something else. After changing the name from XXX to YYY, the following node error occurs:

```
events.js:174
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

 Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available **.***.***.**:3000 
 Emitted 'error' event at:
```

There are so many questions with almost the same error, but I couldn't fix the problem with any of those answers on the thread. I was wondering if someone has faced this specific problem after changing the computer name.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the node again? I ran into this problem once and re-installing the node solved the problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. It worked. But it isn't working when I am on VPN which is weird :( . Gives me the same error! Do I need to do something else for this?

Comment: Probably, you have to edit your hosts file for this and point your machine name to the local host.

Comment: Could you please give me more info on that?

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot about writing the answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing node will fix the main issue.

And for the followup issue of not working on the VPN, you need to update the hosts file on your mac.

1. Open the `/etc/hosts` with admin privileges i.e., `sudo vim /etc/hosts`
2. Add the new machine name with domain pointing to the localhost as follows: 
       `127.0.0.1    machinename.domain.com machinename`
3. Save and exit.

Make sure you have a tabbed space between `127.0.0.1` and the `machinename.domain.com`.

That should get rid of the error message on another network.

Hope this helps.